# How can I kill all headless Chrome instances from the command line on Windows?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

On Mac and Linux you can run

```
pkill -f "(chrome)?(--headless)"
```

to kill all headless Chrome instances.

I'd like something similar that will run on Windows.

Comment: I came here looking for linux and slightly adapted your comment to: `pkill -f "(chrome).*(--headless)"` I think your original post would also kill any other programs that have a headless argument since the chrome part is optional

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `CommandLine` is not easily retrievable through the normal process management commands, so we need to dip into WMI. This tends to make the command more complex, but you can alias it or hide it in a script/function you can reuse.

Here's an example of how you can do this in PowerShell:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'chrome.exe' AND CommandLine LIKE '%--headless%'" | %{Stop-Process $_.ProcessId}
```

Generalising it a bit, we can also get:

```
$name = 'chrome.exe'
$cmdcontains '--headless'
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "Name = '$name' AND CommandLine LIKE '%$cmdcontains%'" | %{Stop-Process $_.ProcessId}
```

Alternatively, `Name` can use a looser matching, or we can filter purely on the CommandLine like you're currently doing:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "CommandLine LIKE '%chrome.exe%--headless%'" | %{Stop-Process $_.ProcessId}
```

More generally, you can extend it to a cmdlet via script: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff677563.aspx

---

The same process applies if you want to do this in cmd, except you'd need to grab the PIDs from the output of `wmic` and pass it into `taskkill`.

Answer (score 0):

in case someone gets here by google search... On OSX this also works:

```
sudo killall Google\ Chrome
```